# Throttle a file share in Windows Server (2008 R2)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-share

We are in the process of moving our central storage to SharePoint and people are complaining about slowness because our former file share is so blazingly fast. Does anyone know a way for me to slow down or throttle access speed to a windows server file share to gradually make the perceived difference negligible, or even make SharePoint seem faster?

Comment: Take RAM out of the file server.  Drop the page file to about 100 MB....Yeah...no.  Not really.  In actuality, this is a terrible solution at all.

Comment: A few questions come to mind... How fast is blazingly fast? Why not try BLOB caching on the Sharepoint database server? How do you keep a job with this attitude towards user experience?

Comment: You could do per-port throttling on the switches the server's connected to, or you could just work on making Sharepoint faster.

Comment: Yea I know it's a poor solution to the problem. But users are refusing to use SharePoint because it's "web" and inherently slower than a simple mounted drive. There is no way to make it faster than a share. I just want to "change their perceptions" on the subject.

Comment: Remove their old option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Technical Answer

Simply use one of a myriad of third party software tools to throttle bandwidth to and from the server, or put it behind a managed port on a firewall that can do the same.

### Correct Answer

This is a personnel issue. Get business leaders to throw their weight behind one decision or the other. Technical solutions will always fail to *truly* solve personnel issues, especially when the technical "solution" is based on deception.

Comment: I agree fully. I'm working that angle also. Thanks.

Comment: @CodeGrue I figured you knew that, but I thought I'd state the obvious anyway. You can choke the connection down with traffic shaping tools (I won't list any since SF frowns on product recommendations; things get out of date quick so this answer would be less useful for someone in even just a few years), but the ultimate solution is for a manager, director, VP, or C-level exec to drop the hammer on people.

Comment: I tried to enlist the CEO, but he is too comfortable on the shared drive and doesn't want to authorize a cutoff. In fact, he wants files to still be mirrored to the shared drive in read only mode after the cutover. I'm being realistic trying to find other ways to encourage people to switch.

Comment: @CodeGrue Then you are, in a word, screwed. =/